# How to run task parallel and wait for second if first Fails ,otherwise reply back and let the second one running

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a situation.

I am creating a REST API which is going to perform two tasks parallelly. If the first task executed successfully, no need to wait for the second and reply 200 to the caller. But if the First task fails, need to wait for the second task and response will be dependent on the second task.

Could anyone suggest an optimum way to do it in java ?

Comment: Are you using multithreading? Could you add related code part to understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

If it's parallel tasks that you want, you may use [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).
They offer you the cancel method and you can wait for the result if you want.

Considering this simple task :

```
class MyTask implements Callable<String> {
    private mStr;
    MyTask(String str) {
        mStr = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() { 
        return mStr;
    }
}
```

And there is the usage:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<String> task1 = executor.submit(new MyTask("My first parallel task"));
Future<String> task2 = executor.submit(new MyTask("My second parallel task"));

try {
   String result = task1.get();
   String result2 = task2.get();
} catch(ExecutionException ex) { 
   System.out.println("Something went wrong when executing parallel tasks :" + ex); 
}
```